# Where can I get a public SSL certificate if I don't own a domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We built web APIs using Spring Boot. It is currently deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. HTTPS is enabled with a self-signed certificate for development and testing. We plan to go live soon, so probably need to get a public certificate from a Certificate Authority.

Amazon has a certificate manager which is the easiest way to get a certificate for application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. However, it requires some DNS set up on the server side which means you have to own the domain. I also looked at a popular free CA, Letsencrypt. But it also requires domain validation. We don't own a domain yet. The APIs are still using the long url from Beanstalk environment, something like `my-app.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`. I wonder if there is any website to download domain independent certificate which can be used for Beanstalk web applications without a domain?

Comment: I don't think this kind of question belongs in this stack mac.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource are off topic here, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why not just spend the $10 and register your domain?

Comment: @Brian I ended up doing that. Registered domain on Route53 and am not getting certificate via ACM. A `.io` domain costs $39/yr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If somebody could get a certificate for a domain he does not own he would be able to impersonate that domain, for example within a man in the middle attack. This would essentially break the security of HTTPS since encryption will not help to protect your data if you don't do the encryption with the real server but instead with a server owned by the attacker.

That's why there is no such thing as  domain independent certificate. And that's why you should not be able to get a certificate for a domain you don't control.